# App - Displaying different pages on the Page Tab and the Landing Page

Tags: facebook

I am trying to make a FB app which does the following:

i) The app is present on the page Tab. When the user click the pageTab, she is shown a screen[A1] where she can invite her friends to this app.

ii) When the friend gets the notification, she sees another screen [A2] which tells about the app.

What are the ways to do this?

I was wondering if there is a way to identify the source of the requests (other than the url on browser) to differentiate between the two requests to the Apps so that I can render the appropriate screens [A1] or [A2] based on if it is clicked from the PageTab or directly the invite notification.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/, section „Accepting a User Request” – your app will get the request id(s), and can then read out the details of the request(s).

If the pure fact that the user came by your app following a request notification isn’t enough for you in your scenario, you can also pass an additional *data* parameter while making the request, read that out when processing the request, and let your app react accordingly.

And remember that it is *your* responsibility to delete requests once the user has acted upon them. (Also described in detail in the documentation.)